# Flutter Wrap widget problem - spacing not working in the container widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

My Flutter App is laggy right now so here's the drawing:

My current three container is like this:
[Current Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAYGP.png)

I wanted to spacing the containers like this:
[Desired Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7stlc.png)

I tried to use Wrap like this in the body.

`body:Wrap(Spacing:32, ...`

but it's not working. any solution may help

Comment: Need more code to help you on this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wrap(spacing: 32, ...` should work, if it doesn't, something else might be incorrect. Although you could just use `margin` property in your `Container`, like this:

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 32),
    ....
```

This should create some blank space around each container.